# java Eclipse selenium webdriver throws exception

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

So I was just writing a simple test program to open google in firefox. And it's not working.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:312)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:122)
    at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

My code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("Hello Google...");
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the very clear error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please download Geckodriver from below mentioned link
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

In Your Test program set Geckodriver path-

```
public class links {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "D:\\vidya\\selenium\\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
```